# How do I stop Civilization V from freezing and crashing on "next turn"/

Tags: civilization-5, technical-issues

Sometimes, when clicking the "next turn" button on a late turn, Civilization V freezes (and in the background Windows shows an error, so it actually crashes). When this happens it is reproducible - i.e. if it crashes when trying to go from turn 396 to 397, then when loading again turn 396 or 390 (from the autosave) or even earlier, it will still crash.

Searching online shows this happens to other players as well, typically on late game turns in huge maps - but I was not able to find a solution. Does anyone know of a way to continue playing once this happens?

Comment: OS (including 32vs64), and amount of memory?

Comment: @CRoss Win7 64bit, 4GB. The game usually runs pretty smoothly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some experimentation, I guessed it was because the game was trying to show me too many things on the turn transition - so what I did was to **change to strategic view** (<kbd>F10</kbd>) just before clicking "next turn", then the transition was quick and I was able to reach the next turn without crashing. I then changed back from strategic to normal view.

I didn't have to do it in subsequent turns, passing that turn everything seemed to go back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

This often happened to me as well - whenever i clicked next turn, the game would freeze when taking the turn of the city states. I tried finding a solution on the internet, but i didnt find anything. I then tried some launch options and finally i found a solution.
-In your games library, right click on civ 5 and select "properties"
-click on "set launch options"
-type in the following in the quotation marks (but dont type the quotation marks): "-high"
This should have fixed the isue, it sets civ 5 to run on high priority. Apologies if this doesnt work for you, but it worked fine for me :D